# Cannot see console.logs in Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

For some reason my Google Chrome console has changed to my usual preference and I'm unable to figure out why.

Would anyone know why I can no longer just see my console.logs();?

This is what I'm currently seeing, the only option that will bring up logs is the Verbose option, but of course I am getting an overwhelming amount of messages in the verbose option of console logs.

[image]

Even the official documentation shows the console differently:

https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/

Comment: Check the filter icon

Comment: Try disabling all your add-ons temporarily

Comment: @MendiBarel I do not see a filter icon anymore :(

Comment: @j08691 Tried this and it is still the same

Comment: @de__bug Try setting your options to "info". I'm on "info" and it's showing everything.

Comment: @SealedSaint This will show me my logs, but I believe this is showing everything https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console I just want to see console.log();

Comment: anything there?: chrome://conflicts/

Comment: @MendiBarel No unfortunately this will not load

Comment: reinstall fresh chrome

Answer (score 2):

From the Developer Tools window, hit your F1 key.  That should bring up Settings > Preferences. At the bottom right of that window click the button 'Restore defaults and reload.'

Comment: No sorry Krypton I have tried this and it is still not working :(

Comment: Can you at least see the filter icon now?

Comment: So unfortunately I cannot see it

Answer (score 1):

Just go to console in the browser and at the top have gear Icon click on and there at the very bottom you find "Restore defaults and reload" just have a hit on it there you go.